# Add a security Group in another Security Group in Azure AD using Graph Client C#

Tags: c#, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add the Security Group(child) to another Security Group(parent) using the GraphClient in a console application

```
var childdirectoryObject = new DirectoryObject
{
Id = groupName.Id
};
var targetGroupCollection = Task.Run(async () => await graphClient.Groups[parentGroupid].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(childdirectoryObject)).Status;
Task.WaitAll();
Console.WriteLine(targetGroupCollection);
```

But I am getting `WaitingForActivation` as an output.  Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like not so much a graph issue, but rather a c# threading question: 
I'm not super well versed in c# threading. but here is a thread with people discussing something very similar. [Task.WaitAll keeps in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046471/task-waitall-keeps-in-loop)

this sounds like whats happening to you, either your tasks are not starting or you're stuck in a deadlock.

Hope that helps, 
Regards,

Comment: Yes, the issue lies with System.Threading.Tasks that you're using and not with Graph API!!